# hiding the address bar in ios and android browsers

Tags: android, iphone, web

I am developing a mobile web application for iOS and android phones using `iscroll`.
I need the ability to hide the address bar of the browser as soon as the page loads.
After doing much research I found that the `window.scrollat(0,1)` needs to be invoked.
However, even this is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't hide the address bar of safari from web side. This have to be done in the mobile application side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the address bar from your webpage. Hiding the address bar (if possible by the browser itself) needs to be done by the browser. So there is no command for doing this